# Payload data manipulation

Tags: karate

My payload looks something like this. I am not posting the entire request.

```
{
"Package": {
"@UniqueID": "Some383",
"Content": {
  "Application": {
    "@UniqueID": "SUB1536201342468",
    "PersonApplicant": [
      {
        "@ApplicantType": "Whateever",
        "@Citizenship": "IND",
```

I am able to set values to the payload

```
* set request $.Package.Content.Application.@UniqueID = someID
```

But, I am unable to get a value from the request for a second service call. Below is the code I use.

```
* set type= request $.Package.Content.Application.PersonApplicant.@ApplicantType
```

I get the below error, Please advice.

```
jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ParserException: <eval>:1:13 Expected ; but found $
lixiInitiate $.Package.Content.Application.PersonApplicant.@ApplicantType
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the docs and examples carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions

```
* set type = request.Package.Content.Application.PersonApplicant.@ApplicantType
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Went through the documentation, fixed the issue with this. * def type = get request.Package.Content.Application.PersonApplicant[0].@ApplicantType